# NSString Slicing in Objective C (right to left)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsstring, slice

How can I substring an NSString with the last x characters? Right to left.

In python it takes only one line!

```
>>> "string"[-4:]
'ring'
```

Comment: [String Programming Guide: Combining and Extracting Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000148-SW5) | [`NSString` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 16):

It should be a one liner in Objective-C, too:

```
NSString *substring = [string substringFromIndex:[string length] - x];
```

Comment: @Martino if you are happy with an answer, you should accept it by clicking the green √

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer you're looking for by checking out the documentation for NSString from the apple.developer.com website.

Specifically, you can use the `substringFromIndex:` method.

For example, if you already have a string called `originalString` and you
want to obtain a string that has the last x characters. You can do:

`NSString* slicedString = [originalString substringFromIndex: originalString.length-x]`

This should return a string with the last x characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = **Some integer value**
    NSString *string = [originalString substringFromIndex:index];
    NSString *string = [originalString substringToIndex:index];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *substring = [initialstring substringFromIndex:[intialstring length] - x];
```